# How to change the color of element in SVG Image in Android

Tags: android, svg, colors, android-vectordrawable

I downloaded the following svg image:
[image]

This image is a screen shot from Android Studio, it is a grey rectangle with round border and plus which is transparent. Here's the following file xml:

```
<vector android:autoMirrored="true" android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24" android:viewportWidth="24"
  android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path  android:fillColor="#e8e8e8"
        android:pathData="M19,3L5,3c-1.11,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v14c0,1.1 0.89,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L21,5c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM17,13h-4v4h-2v-4L7,13v-2h4L11,7h2v4h4v2z"/>
</vector>
```

I would like to change the color of the element "plus" inside the rectangle from transparent to black, How can I do that?

I found the solution as the following:
I just download the plus svg image and I create a rectangle shape
as the following

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#e8e8e8" />

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

And I use it like that

```
android:background="@drawable/rectangle_shape"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
```

Answer (score 0):

To change solid color, android:fillColor is used to change the color of the solid.